# Git: Add commits to history that were 2 commits earlier

Tags: git

I have a git repo which looks like this:

```
A -- B --C -- HEAD
```

Now I want to go back to **A**, make some change then rebase **B** and **C** on top of that. So I want my updated history looks like:

```
A -- A1 -- A2 -- B -- C
```

None of these changes has been published. I kinda think `git checkout A` could help. But I could not figure out the workflow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be more than one way to do this. A workflow that I would find clear would be:

1. git checkout A
2. git checkout -b a-edits
3. do your commits
4. git checkout master
5. git rebase a-edits

Comment: I tried this already. But I found the new branch has it parent pointing before A...not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: @davidshen84 It doesn't matter where the parent points. Since the parent commit will still be linearly on the same commit stream, you'll get the desired effect.